# Fire onbeforeunload only when window is closed (includes working example)

Tags: javascript, events

I want to fire the onbeforeunload event only when the tab or browser is closed and not upon refresh, link click and so on. I found a site where that works: https://checkout.deindeal.ch/

Steps to fire the event in Chrome:

1. Put something into the cart
2. Click on "Zur Kasse"
3. Close tab
4. onbeforeunload Message is shown and a popup opens. onbeforeunload events like refresh will not fire. I debugged their code, but could not find the place where they exclude those events or whatsoever.

Anyone out there who can find the correct place in the code?

Thanks!

Comment: In a post from 2012, though the question is about IE8, [Antyrat's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10637604/1169519) stands for all browsers, even today.

Comment: I added something to the cart (I think, it's not in English) and closing the tab did nothing.  No `onbeforeunload` was triggered.  Chrome Version 37.0.2062.124 m on Windows 7 x64.

Answer (score 2):

For readers that want to use `onbeforeunload`,

The event **`onbeforeunload` should be used for preventing user's data loss**, like filled in forms and other data that are not saved and will be lost upon page refresh.

Using **`onbeforeunload` to prevent a user from leaving your page is annoying** and will not stop the user from leaving.

---

**You can not detect** **a browser tab refresh button press**, unless the user use a shortcut that you can detect with key press (like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>).
More info here : 
[javascript beforeunload detect refresh versus close](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11453741/javascript-beforeunload-detect-refresh-versus-close)

---

**Old answer was removed in order not to mislead anyone (it was not working on nowadays browsers).**

More stack overflow links related on `onbeforeunload` use:

[How can i get the destination url in javascript onbeforeunload event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1686687/how-can-i-get-the-destination-url-in-javascript-onbeforeunload-event)

[How to prevent calling onbeforeunload when page refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5606331/how-to-prevent-calling-onbeforeunload-when-page-refresh)

[Fire onbeforeunload confirm alert for external sites only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29408083/fire-onbeforeunload-confirm-alert-for-external-sites-only)

Comment: Thanks, how would that help in my case? When I close the browser window, the goto var still contains my domain ... did I miss something?

Comment: `new URL(e.target.URL).hostname` doesn't work for me: `JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support this action`. IE11.

Comment: IE do not support URL object. You can get the host url by checking if a e.target.href exist and parsing it.